# Substract column means from column values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 14 numeric variables and 310 rows.
I would like to deduct the column means row-wise from the values in the columns and then create a new data frame from the results.
I've tried the following, but this provides incorrect results:

```
new_df <- df - colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: `scale(df,center=T,scale=F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sweep` :

```
sweep(df, 2,colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE))

#   a  b
#1 -2 -2
#2 -1 -1
#3  0  0
#4  1  1
#5  2  2
```

Or double transpose :

```
t(t(df) - colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `rep`licate the `colMeans`

```
df - colMeans(df)[col(df)]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
```